# Regression to determine if delay of processing points in a process affected output

Tags: regression, statsmodels, non-linear-regression

Every month we go thru the same thing.  We receive the files from our client, the files need to be decrypted, they need to be loaded, they need to be processed and the output created.

We know that timeliness affects the quantity of our output.

I want to create a regression to see which process we need to be quicker with, which process contributes more to the output.

Let's say we should receive the files from our client on the 6th.  I was thinking about creating a dataset of delays of each point from the 6th.  However, because when each point starts depends on when the previous one ends, this would introduce covariance.  How can I eliminate the covariance?  Have each point be the delay from when the previous one ended?

Is a linear model the best approach for this?  Are there other models?  I've heard of Bayesian, I'm not really familiar with it, but I wasn't sure if it would be helpful.

Comment: There could be a non-work-related delay from when one process ends and the next process begins - such as a holiday or weekend. I would try to use *business days* from when the previous process ended.

Comment: Yes, I will do that, thanks for the comment.